# How to trace the origin of a weird spacing?

Tags: css

I have done something less brilliant but no matter how much i check in Firebug, i can't see any style that causes the buttons to get this weird margin on the left side. In fact, they don't even flash (on mouse over) except at the leftmost edge.

The question is twofold. What did the evil computer did?

And, more importantly, how does one trace the source of this weird layout?

The demo page can be found [here](http://viltersten.somee.com/TvGuide/TvGuide.aspx).

Comment: `input[type="button"], input[type="submit"]` has a left margin of 120px. Isn't this the problem?

Comment: You mean the green buttons that have `margin-left: 120px`?

Comment: yes its the margin-left property that is pushing your buttons right side.

Comment: Sigh... I was so focused on restyling the divs that i didn't think about the margin on the buttons. That's an hour well spent... What moron put margin on the buttons, instead of the div around them?! Thanks guys. Nevertheless, it's very easy to miss even in Firebug. On my machine it looked like an extra div between the buttons and the textarea...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`input[type="button"], input[type="submit"]` has a left margin of 120px.